# Showing an inner product space is complete

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, inner-products

I'm working through Ward Cheneys *Analysis for Applications* and I'm a bit stuck on this exercise from Section 2.2:

> Prove that if $M=M^{\perp\perp}$ for every closed linear subspace $M$ in an inner product space $V$, then $V$ is complete.

To clarify, $V$ is assumed to be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. I've thought about trying to prove the contrapositive. Given a Cauchy sequence $\left( x_n \right)$, one possible closed subspace we might consider is

$$U=\{ u\in V : \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \langle u,x_n \rangle =0 \},$$

but I really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Well, if we consider the completion of $V$ and suppose the limit of $\left(x_n\right)$, call it $x$ is not in $V$, then we have $U^\perp \cap V = \{0\}$. So, in $V$, $U^\perp=\{0\}$. Then this implies $U=V$. But since V is dense in its completion, then we must have $x=0$. However, we assumed $x\notin V$.